# Derivative of $f(x,y)=(\sin x,x+y)$ direct from definition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, analysis

In class, my professor gave an example showing $f(x,y)=(\sin x ,x+y)$  is differentiable directly from definition which I am trying to understand.

What the professor showed us in class is as follows:

> Show that $f(x,y)=(\sin x, x^2+y^2)$ is differentiable directly from definition.
>
> Fix $(x_{0}, y_{0}) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$.
>
> Consider the linear transformation $L:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined as
>
> $$
> \left[\begin{array}{cc}
> \cos x_0 & 0 \\
> 1 & 1
> \end{array}\right]
> $$
>
> Then we want to look at $f(x, y)-f\left(x_{0}, y_{0}\right)-L\left(x-x_{0}, y-y_{0}\right)$.
> By the mean value theorem in one variable, we have
> $$
> \begin{gathered}
> \sin x-\sin x_{0}=\cos (\hat{x})\left(x-x_{0}\right) \quad \hat{x} \in\left(x_{0}, x\right) \\
> =\cos \left(x_{0}\right)(x-x_0)+O\left(x-x_{0}\right)^{2}
> \end{gathered}
> >$$
> and considering the norm we have
> $$
> \begin{array}{r}
> \left\|f(x, y)-f\left(x_{0}, y_{0}\right)-L\left(x-x_{0}, y-y_{0}\right)\right\| \\
> =\|(\sin(x)-\sin(x_0),x-x_0+y-y_0)-(\cos(x_0)(x-x_0),x-x_0+y-y_0)\|\\
> =\|(\cos(x_0)(x-x_0)+O((x-x_0)^2,x-x_0+y-y_0)-(\cos(x_0)(x-x_0),x-x_0+y-y_0))\| \\
> =\sqrt{O\left(x-x_{0}\right)^{4}} \\
> \leq M\left(x-x_{0}\right)^{2}
> \end{array}
> $$
> which implies that
> $$
> \frac{\left\|f(x, y)-f\left(x_{0}, y_{0}\right)-L\left(x-x_{0}, y-y_{0}\right)\right\|}{\left\|x-x_{0}\right\|} \leq M
> $$
> and as $M \rightarrow 0$, we are done and the derivative exists.

Why was the mean value theorem required? Woulnd't this follow just the same from the Taylor expansion?

Comment: He certainly must have exhibited the $L$. I suspect what you've posted is not the entirety of what he presented. Where's the discussion of the second component of the function. Clearly he is using $L(x-x_0,y-y_0) = \big(\cos(x_0)(x-x_0), (x-x_0)+(y-y_0)\big)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you he did indeed. I have updated the question.

Comment: The $L$ should have $x_0$ in it, of course. Yes, you're right; it is just the definition of the derivative in one variable (well, with $o(x-x_0)$) or Taylor, and the mean value theorem is not really relevant. I also think the $\sqrt{O(x-x_0)^4}$ is silly. There's no need to be squaring things here.

Comment: @TedShifrin Why don't we need to square things? Isnt using the taylor approximation what enables us to bound the norm?

Comment: I'm just saying we can see that $\|(a+b)-a\| = \|b\|$ without using the Euclidean norm explicitly. I don't think in this case we even need the triangle inequality, but it's generally useful :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you so much for your help. Also, shouldn't the quantitiy in the denominator of the last step be $\|(x,y)-(x_0,y_0)\|$? As this is a derivative in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Yes, you're completely correct. By the way, you might find some of my YouTube lectures (linked in my profile) helpful as you progress through this material and onward.

Comment: @TedShifrin Wow what a great resource I have bookmarked them for reference during this semester